# Programmatically determine comment syntax by language type

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, file-io, comments, analysis

If I have some source code files eg:

```
index.html
index.js
hello_world.py
tests.cpp
main.m
...(a ton more misc files)
```

I already have a way of determining the language eg: "HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "C++", "Objective-C"

(Presuming the file content supports commenting)
I would like to analyze the contents and determine lines of code comments vs lines not considered code comments. (I'm working in Python). In-short is there a tool[kit]|Library|cmd-line-tool that would provide me the functionality to determine this?

P.S Even an exhaustive list of "language": "syntax of languages comment[s]" would be beneficial.

Comment: Requests for libraries/tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but you might be able to do what you want using a code syntax highlighting library like [Pygments](https://pygments.org/), which has lexers for many languages that can classify tokens as comments (among other things).

Comment: certainly not exhaustive but [here's a list of language comments](https://github.com/lutobler/vis-commentary/blob/master/init.lua#L8)

Comment: [Wikipedia has a long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Comments) although it's probably not *exhaustive* (and may well contain some flaws).